# Xamarin.forms iOS app rejected on app icon

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I've been trying to publish my xamarin.forms iOS app to the app store but it keeps getting rejected with the following message: **We noticed the app icon displayed on the device and the large icon displayed on the App Store do not sufficiently match, which makes it difficult for users to find the app they just downloaded.**

Apparently my device icon does not match the app store icon. Somehow my app is returning the xamarin default logo when apple is testing. But my app's icon shows correctly when I test on my device. In my project I've included all my app's icons under Assests: AppIcon and LaunchImage. Is there anything else I am missing ?

Apple also included the xamarin default image which is named "Icon-72.png", I searched my entire project to replace this image with my app's image and I can't find it. Please help

Comment: the first thing I would try is to clear the bin and obj folders before doing another build.  Sometimes old artifacts don't get overwritten as they should when building

Comment: Thanks, will try that

Comment: @Jason after deleting bin and obj folder and submitting a new build, the app got rejected again with the same error. :( . Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Is there anywhere else in the iOS project I'm meant to change the app/device icon? Except in asset catalog? Because I can't seem to find the "Icon-72.png" that apple provided in the error message :(

Comment: You must keep the image(named `App Store`) set in Asset Catalogs the same as the image you provide in Itunes Connect.

Comment: @ColeXia , this issue has been resolved. I've set my icons correctly from the beginning but the fault was on Apple's side. Luckily they spotted it and my app is now published :D